# How to extract website data into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I wanna extract the rating of a hotel room from Expedia in Google sheet. Unfortunatley, my code doesn't work. Can you take a look?

```
=IMPORTXML(https://www.expedia.co.in/Manila-Hotels-ZEN-Rooms-Pioneer-Street.h17368867.Hotel-Information,"//span[@class='rating-number']")
```

Comment: Can you provide us your code (something more)?

Comment: You're trying to read XML (`IMPORTXML`) from an URL that doesn't return an XML... Maybe you could start your research here: http://developer.expedia.com/docs/public/api/ to see if Expedia provides the information you want on their API.

Comment: `importxml` can import HTML too.

Comment: 'Imports data from any of various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds.' from [help doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

`importXml()` can import simple HTML, but it does not work with the most of modern sites. In this case too, `importXml()` was not able to retrieve `div`, `span`, etc. Nevertheless, you can get the whole `html` and then parse it.

Just change your XPath query to `//html`. And seen from the source, you know where and how to find the rating. So just get it by `=mid(A2, find("out of 5.0", A2)-4, 3)`.

Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hDqBnBkpZFqdHXoyvrsNx0wVsv_KNAwVe2Sp0n_jsiU/). I tested it with a few other hotels and it worked fine.